# How to break before small spans in fluent list

Tags: html, css, list

My code:

```
<span style=''></span> Description <span style=''></span> Description <span style=''></span> Description
```

Shows like (with 'O' representing an image that the CSS defines for the span):

```
O Description O Description O Description
```

But when the content column width is small, it shows like:

```
O Description O
Description O
Description
```

I would like it to show like:

```
O Description
O Description
O Description
```

What is the best CSS or other way to do this?

Comment: Non-breaking spaces or actual list items.

Comment: It's a no-go to wrap the span/image and the description inside another element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `white-space: nowrap` for the parent of the items you want to hook together

```css
.non-breaking {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="non-breaking"><span style=''>0</span> Description</span>
<span class="non-breaking"><span style=''>0</span> Description</span>
<span class="non-breaking"><span style=''>0</span> Description</span>
```

Here's a codepen so you can play with the viewport's width and check the line breaks: https://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/zWPMPe/left/

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

**html**

```
<span>Description</span>
<span>Description </span>
<span>Description</span>
```

**css**

```
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

span:before {
  content: 'O';
  position: absolute;
  color:#000;
  left:0;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/falatory/0oj99L37/6/)**